# More pythonic way to "connect" two objects

Tags: python, oop

[In a blog post analyzing Python PDF libraries](http://slott-softwarearchitect.blogspot.com/2012/02/pdf-reading.html), [S.Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/s-lott) makes the following comment:

Here's one example of remarkably poor programming:

```
#Connect the parser and document objects.    
parser.set_document(doc)    
doc.set_parser(parser)
```

Only one of these two is needed; the other is trivially handled as part of the setter method.

What is the a Pythonic way of doing this via the setter method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Parser(object):
    def set_document(self, doc):
        doc.set_parser(self)
        # whatever
```

Though in practice, I would redesign the document and parser classes to avoid circular references. Not only do they add conceptual complexity, they interfere with garbage collection as well unless weak references are used.

Answer (score 2):

I guess what the author means is this:

```
class Parser(object):
  def set_document(self, doc):
    self.doc = doc
    doc.parser = self
```

The other setter, `set_parser()`, can be argued to be redundant.